# Undefined method 'strftime' for nil:NilClass When value is not nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, null, strftime

I've got an odd error with displaying times in Rails

```
<%= Time.zone.parse(e["start_time"])%>
```

Displays a full time stamp string. "2010-09-02 18:00:00 -0500"

```
<%= Time.zone.parse(e["start_time"]).strftime()%>
```

Shows the expected error that I have (0 of 1) arguments supplied. Again, expected.

```
<%= Time.zone.parse(e["start_time"]).strftime("%Y")%>
```

Shows an error "Undefined method 'strftime' for nil:NilClass".

So my e["start_time"] field *is* populated, but I can't figure out why specifying the argument that strftime() wants results in a Nil value.

Comment: Issue resolved. Some events were not returning time information from the Google Calendar API. Sanitize your inputs, kids!

Comment: Also try not to call methods on things that might return `nil` as that leads to unfortunate incidents like this. It would be a good idea to wrap this in a helper method that can handle those cases more elegantly.

Answer (score 1):

It works when I try it:

```
irb(main):005:0> Time.zone.parse("2012-04-05 12:00:02").strftime("%Y")
=> "2012"
```

Even:

```
irb(main):006:0> Time.zone.parse("2012-04-05 12:00:02 -0500").strftime("%Y")
=> "2012"
```

What is the value in `e["start_time"]`?

Comment: `Time.zone.parse("2010-09-02 18:00:00 -0500").strftime("%Y")
  => "2010"`